# Reasons why XLST sentence won't match XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a few xhtmls coming from different systems that I need to parse into mine, I decided to use transformations to convert them all to a standard xml format that my application can then parse and import. I managed to get one working but something is wrong with the second and I have no idea what, since I copy-pasted the code.

Let's see an extract of the first xml and transformation:

*xml*

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- some really deep tree structure including a table -->
    <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="md-maketable">
        <tbody>
            <tr valign="middle" class="md-maketable-reg-tr">
                <!-- some tds inside -->
            </tr>
            <tr valign="middle" class="md-maketable-reg-tr">
                <!-- some tds inside -->
            </tr>
            <!-- these trs repeat n number of times -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</html>
```

*transformation*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <movements>
            <xsl:for-each select="//tr[@class=&quot;md-maketable-reg-tr&quot;]">
                <movement>
                    <!-- parsing some movements (uninteresting) -->
                </movement>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </movements>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*result*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<movements>
      <movement>
         <!-- some movement data -->
      </movement>
</movements>
<!-- n number of movements -->
```

Now on to the second one

*xml*

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- some really deep tree structure including a table -->
    <table id="transactions" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="tr:1" class="interlaceOne">
                <!-- some tds inside -->
            </tr>
            <tr id="tr:2" class="interlaceOne">
                <!-- some tds inside -->
            </tr>
            <!-- these trs repeat n number of times -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</html>
```

*transformation*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <movements>
            <xsl:for-each select="//tr[@class=&quot;interlaceOne&quot;]">
                <movement>
                    <!-- parsing some movements (uninteresting) -->
                </movement>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </movements>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*result*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<movements>
</movements>
```

P.S. I'm actually using a different select on the second one, but the one I need wasn't bringing any results, so I changed it to this for debugging which also didn't work, so I'm assuming whatever fixes this issue will also solve the problem for the real select.

Comment: Please post enough code (XML+XSL) to enable us to reproduce the issue. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve --- P.S. If I had to guess, I would say your second XML's elements are  in a *namespace*.

Comment: Added more detail, but I can't post the whole xml file. How would I find the namespace? And how do I change the transformation to accommodate it? I'm new to XSLT so I might be overlooking "obvious" things.

Comment: Well, now you show that **both** are in the xhtml namespace (`xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`) - so I don't see how your first transformation can be working. I suggest you do a search, as there are *many* previous answers explaining how to handle namespaces (for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590320/not-getting-data-to-transform-xml/22590777#22590777)

Comment: Actually removing the namespace did fix the problem, if you write an answer I'll vote you up! Thanks.

Comment: Removing the namespace  is not a good solution.  XSLT can and should handle the XML input as is.

Comment: Noted, I'll look into it as well, like I said I'm new to this and I'm still in the proof of concepts. But I'll read on about namespaces in xslt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, your XML input is in the XHTML namespace (`xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`).

To process an input that uses a namespace, you must declare the namespace in your stylesheet, assign it a prefix and use that prefix when addressing the document nodes - see an example here: [Not getting data to transform Xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590320/not-getting-data-to-transform-xml/22590777#22590777)