# Transforming the namespace child(sub) element using XSLT

Tags: xslt

**XML**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!-- Edited by XMLSpy -->
 <h:catalog xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd>
 </h:catalog>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"      xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
<xsl:template match="/h:catalog/cd">
    <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="country"/></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*I am expecting below output from the above transformation, but i am not getting*
*Need Your help to display in below format, Struggling a lot because of the namespace child element*

**Expected Output:**

```
<tr xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
    <td>Empire Burlesque</td>
    <td>USA</td>
</tr>
```

This is just an example i gave my query is: How can i transform the child element, whose parent has the namespace? example:

```
<app:ApplicationRequest xmlns:app="http://*/applicationRequest">
      <BusinessChannel> 
       <!-- SOME STUFF -->
      </BusinessChannel>
</app:ApplicationRequest>.
```

I need to display the contents of BusinessChannel using

```
  <xsl:template match="/app:ApplicationRequest/BusinessChannel">
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Why do you have the html namespace in your XML? Your Output seems to be html, but your source isn't. Maybe you are mixing something up here. Your source should not even be valid because there is no `catalog` defined in html.

Comment: This is just an example i gave my query is:

Comment: This is just an example i gave, my query is: How can i transform the child element, whose parent has the namespace? example: <app:ApplicationRequest xmlns:app="http://*/applicationRequest"> <BusinessChannel> <!-- SOME STUFF --> </BusinessChannel></app:ApplicationRequest>. I need to display the contents of <BusinessChannel> using <xsl:template match="/app:ApplicationRequest/BusinessChannel">

Comment: I edied the code above. Kindly have a look.

Comment: Ok, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654466/ignoring-xml-namespace-prefix-while-selecting-elements-xs I think that should help

Comment: I had a look with the above link, but unfortuantely this dint resolve my issue. :(, beause in my sub element there is no namespace.. only parent has the namespace

Comment: If i am giving the match="/app:ApplicationRequest". it works. But when i give like  : match="/app:ApplicationRequest/BusinessChannel". Its not working.

Comment: "*I am expecting below output from the above transformation, but i am not getting*" What ARE you getting? Your example produces the expected output - see: http://xsltransform.net/pPgCcoy If you want to discuss **another input** and **another stylesheet**, please edit your question accordingly and do not post code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match an element disregarding its namespace, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654466/ignoring-xml-namespace-prefix-while-selecting-elements-xslt) you have to use `local-name()`, so in your case:

```
<xsl:template match="/app:ApplicationRequest/*[local-name()='BusinessChannel']">
```

Comment: Thanks for your continuous support. But it did not help me.